# If P=NP then all languages in P are NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, p-vs-np

I know that if $P=NP$ then all of the languages in $NP$ are $NP-Complete$, but what about those in $P$?

I assume yes, because $P \subseteq NP$, but I just want to check.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both facts are wrong. The empty problem $\emptyset$ (the decision problem whose answer is always *false*) is in both $\mathsf{P}$ and $\mathsf{NP}$, and is not $\mathsf{NP}$-complete.

See [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/155865/why-does-showing-that-a-np-problem-is-not-np-complete-implies-p-neqnp/155866#155866) for some details.

Comment: You are right, except the trivial ones.